# Magento - retrieve image path from ID

Tags: php, magento

i am in product template ( view.phtml ) and I hava an array with the images ID.
How can I retrieve the filename or path from the ID??
Thanks!!!1

Comment: If you are in the view template, what are you doing with image IDs? What happens if the IDs change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply,

```
$array_ids = //your array of ids
$images =  $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();

foreach($array_ids as $id) {
    foreach($images as $image) {
        if($id == $image['id']) {
            //do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tip:** `var_dump($_product->debug())`

To retrieve the main image paths, you can use the following:

- `$_product->getImage()`
- `$_product->getSmallImage()`
- `$_product->getThumbnail()`

To retrieve a collection of gallery images, `$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()`. Iterating over the members of this collection as `$image`, you can call `$image->getPath()`. See `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->getMediaGalleryImages()`.